# Datetime pandas sum

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime

Hi everybody I'm working in productivity Data analysis and I have one problem.

I have a large time dataframe (This data is just an example):

01:59:55

00:30:17

00:09:00

00:15:03

How can I sum all of this time data?

I tried a lot of things but they doesn´t works for me. Thanks in advance

Comment: please share the codes that you tried and your expected result

Comment: Try: `pd.to_timedelta(df["column name"]).sum()`

Comment: @AndrejKesely I got this: Invalid type for timedelta scalar: <class 'datetime.time'>

Comment: I convert to str and then use the sum() function and it's works! Thank you so much @AndrejKesely

Answer (score 1):

You need the following line:

```
sum = pd.to_timedelta(df["col1"],unit='s').sum()
```

Following your example:

```
a = '01:59:55'
b = '00:30:17'
d = '00:09:00'
c = '00:15:03'
d = {'col1': [a,b,c,d]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
sum = pd.to_timedelta(df["col1"],unit='s').sum()
```

Output:

```
0 days 02:54:15
```

Comment: Ty @simoncraf this was better.